# Displaying repeating elements from json array only once in table view swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am making an iOS app that displays which movies were filmed in certain cities. I am trying to only display the repeating cities once in one table view, and only the movies filmed in the selected city in another table view. All of my data is being read from a local JSON file I created. Currently, my city table view displays all the cities with repeats and my movie table displays all movies from the JSON file. I would like to have no repeated cities in the city table, and only movies filmed in that city when a city from the city table is selected.

[image: what my app currently displays]

```
import UIKit

class cityTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var movieObject = [Movies]()

    @IBOutlet weak var cityTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var movieTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.cityTable.rowHeight = 50
        self.movieTable.rowHeight = 50

        cityTable.delegate = self
        cityTable.dataSource = self

        movieTable.delegate = self
        movieTable.dataSource = self

        readJson ()
    }

    func readJson() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "movies", ofType: "json") else {return}
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) -> Void in
        // If there is an error, print the error
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            } // end if

            do{
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as AnyObject

                let array = json as? [[String:Any]]

                for eachMovie in array! {
                    if let movie = Movies(json: eachMovie)
                    {
                        self.movieObject.append(movie)
                    }

                    print(self.movieObject)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async{self.cityTable.reloadData()}
                DispatchQueue.main.async{self.movieTable.reloadData()}
            } catch {print(error)}
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movieObject.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let mov:Movies = movieObject[indexPath.row]

        if tableView == cityTable
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cityCell", for: indexPath) as! cityTableViewCell

            //let cityArray = mov.City
            //let index = cityArray?.first

            //print("City: \(String(describing: index))")
            var uniqueCity = [String]()

            for elem in mov.City! {
                if !uniqueCity.contains(elem)
                {
                    uniqueCity.append(elem)
                }
            }

            //print(uniqueCity)
            let index = uniqueCity.first

            cell.cityLabel.text = index

            print("City: \(String(describing: index))")

            return cell
        }
        else //if tableView == movieTable
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "movieCell", for: indexPath) as! movieTableCell

            cell.movieLabel!.text = mov.Title

            return cell
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        let destVC = segue.destination as! movieViewController
        if let indexPath = self.movieTable.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let mov:Movies = movieObject[indexPath.row]

            destVC.tvCity = mov.City!
            destVC.tvTitle = mov.Title
            destVC.tvDirector = mov.Director
            destVC.tvYear = mov.Year
            destVC.tvImage = mov.Image
            destVC.tvWebsite = mov.Website
            destVC.tvAddress = mov.Addresses!
        }
    }
}
```

// my json file

```
     [
  {
  "id": "1",
  "City": ["San Francisco, CA", "Long Beach, CA"],
  "Title": "Titanic",
  "Director": "James Cameron",
  "Year": "1997",
  "Image": "Titanic.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/",
  "Address": [
              "Pier 45, Fisherman's Wharf, San Francisco, CA 94133",
              "4000 E Olympic Plaza Long Beach, CA 90803"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "2",
  "City": ["Los Angeles, CA"],
  "Title": "Fast And Furious",
  "Director": "Justin Lin",
  "Year": "2009",
  "Image": "f&f1.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1013752/",
  "Address": [
              "3680 Wilshire Boulevard, Midtown, Los Angeles, CA 90010",
              "1318 E 7th St Los Angeles, CA 90021",
              "3385 W 8th St, Los Angeles, CA 90005",
              "722 E Kensington Rd, Los Angeles, CA 90026"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "3",
  "City": ["Miami, FL"],
  "Title": "2 Fast 2 Furious",
  "Director": "John Singleton",
  "Year": "2003",
  "Image": "2f2f.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0322259/",
  "Address": [
              "318 NW 23rd St, Miami, FL 33127",
              "401 North Miami Avenue, Miami, FL 33136",
              "3301 Rickenbacker Causeway, Key Biscayne, FL 33149",
              "1 Ocean Drive, South Miami Beach, FL 33139",
              "3555 SW 8th Street, East Coral Gables, FL 33135",
              "1200 South Crandon Boulevard, Key Biscayne, FL 33149"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "4",
  "City": ["Los Angeles, CA"],
  "Title": "The Fast and The Furious",
  "Director": "Rob Cohen",
  "Year": "2001",
  "Image": "tf&tf.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0232500/",
  "Address": [
              "1000 Vin Scully Avenue, Los Angeles, CA 90012",
              "42505 Pacific Coast Highway, Malibu, CA 90265",
              "N Orange Dr, Los Angeles, CA 90038",
              "Center St, Los Angeles, CA 90021"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "5",
  "City": ["Los Angeles, CA" ],
  "Title": "The Fast And The Furious: Tokyo Drift",
  "Director": "Justin Lin",
  "Year": "2006",
  "Image": "tokyodrift.jpeg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0463985/",
  "Address": [
              "San Gabriel Canyon Rd, Azusa, CA 91702",
              "12630 Hawthorne Blvd, Hawthorne, CA 90250",
              "2001 Santa Fe Ave, Long Beach, CA 90810"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "6",
  "City": ["Los Angeles, CA", "Atlanta, GA"],
  "Title": "Furious 7",
  "Director": "James Wan",
  "Year": "2015",
  "Image": "f&f7.jpeg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2820852/",
  "Address": [
              "722 E Kensington Rd, Los Angeles, CA 90026",
              "248 Oakland Ave SE, Atlanta, GA 30312",
              "Mahers Quarry Rd, Stockbridge, GA 30281"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "7",
  "City": ["Miami, FL", "New York, NY"],
  "Title": "Scarface",
  "Director": "Brian de Palma",
  "Year": "1983",
  "Image": "scarface.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086250/",
  "Address": [
              "728 Ocean Drive, Miami Beach, FL 33139",
              "4441 Collins Avenue, Miami, FL 33140",
              "E 41st St, New York, NY 10017"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "8",
  "City": ["Chicago, IL"],
  "Title": "Batman Begins",
  "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
  "Year": "2005",
  "Image": "BmanBegins.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372784/",
  "Address": [
              "141 W Jackson Blvd, Chicago, IL 60604",
              "200 N Franklin St, Chicago, IL 60606",
              "35 E Upper Wacker Dr, Chicago, IL 60601"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "9",
  "City": ["Detroit, MI", "Chicago, IL", "Los Angeles, CA"],
  "Title": "Batman v Superman: Dawn Of Justice",
  "Director": "Zack Snyder",
  "Year": "2016",
  "Image": "BmanvSman.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/",
  "Address": [
              "2301 Clarkston Road, Orion Charter Township, MI 48360",
              "547 East Circle Drive, East Lansing, MI 48824",
              "1106 West Lawrence Avenue, Chicago, IL 60640",
              "1301 Avenida Cesar Chavez, Monterey Park, CA 91754",
              "600 Randolph Street, Detroit, MI 48226"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "10",
  "City": [ "Chicago, IL"],
  "Title": "The Dark Knight",
  "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
  "Year": "2008",
  "Image": "DKnight.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/",
  "Address": [
              "1665 N Sedgwick St, Chicago, IL 60614",
              "404 W Harrison St, Chicago, IL 60607",
              "200 W Randolph St, Chicago, IL 60606",
              "330 N Wabash Ave, Chicago, IL 60611"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "11",
  "City": ["Los Angeles, CA", "New York, NY"],
  "Title": "The Dark Knight Rises",
  "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
  "Year": "2012",
  "Image": "DKnightRises.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/",
  "Address": [
              "725 5th Ave, New York, NY 10022",
              "23 Wall St, New York, NY 10005",
              "433 S Spring St, Los Angeles, CA 90013"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "12",
  "City": ["Los Angeles, CA"],
  "Title": "Superman Returns",
  "Director": "Bryan Singer",
  "Year": "2006",
  "Image": "SmanReturns.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348150/",
  "Address": [
              "1000 Vin Scully Avenue, Los Angeles, CA 90012"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "13",
  "City": ["Los Angeles, CA"],
  "Title": "Suicide Squad",
  "Director": "David Ayer",
  "Year": "2016",
  "Image": "SSquad.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386697/",
  "Address": [
              "617 S Olive St, Los Angeles, CA 90014"
              ]
  },
  {
  "id": "14",
  "City": ["Chicago, IL"],
  "Title": "Home Alone",
  "Director": "Chris Columbus",
  "Year": "1990",
  "Image": "homealone.jpg",
  "Website": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099785/",
  "Address": [
              "671 Lincoln Ave, Winnetka, IL 60093",
              "1024 Lake Ave, Wilmette, IL 60091",
              "10000 W O'Hare Ave, Chicago, IL 60666"
              ]
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
    var uniqueCity = [String]() // make this global

    func readJson() {
         guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "movies", ofType: "json") else {return}
         let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) -> Void in
        // If there is an error, print the error
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        } // end if

        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as AnyObject

            let array = json as? [[String:Any]]

            for eachMovie in array! {
                if let movie = Movies(json: eachMovie)
                {
                    let city = movie.tvCity
                    if (!self.uniqueCity.contains(city)) { // change here
                        self.uniqueCity.append(city)
                    }
                    self.movieObject.append(movie)
                }

                print(self.movieObject)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async{self.cityTable.reloadData()}
            DispatchQueue.main.async{self.movieTable.reloadData()}
        } catch {print(error)}
    }
    task.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (tableView == cityTable) { // change here
        return uniqueCity.count
    }
    return movieObject.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let mov:Movies = movieObject[indexPath.row]

    if tableView == cityTable
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cityCell", for: indexPath) as! cityTableViewCell

        //print(uniqueCity)
        let index = uniqueCity[indexPath.item] // change here

        cell.cityLabel.text = index

        print("City: \(String(describing: index))")

        return cell
    }
    else //if tableView == movieTable
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "movieCell", for: indexPath) as! movieTableCell

        cell.movieLabel!.text = mov.Title

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! After changing the parts you changed in my code, In the func tableView(...cellForRowAt...) in the line " cell.cityLabel.text = index ", I am getting the error "Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?' ". Do you have any further suggestions how to fix that error?

Comment: Are you sure that you define correct `var uniqueCity = [String]()`

Comment: `uniqueCity[indexPath.item]` check your code, did you do this ?

Comment: Yes I did. When I do  `var uniqueCity = [String]()` I get two errors in `if (!self.uniqueCity.contains(city)) { // Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'
        self.uniqueCity.append(city)  //Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'
  }` but when I do `var uniqueCity = [[String]]()`, the only error i get is in the comment I previously posted